# Download de arquivo em banco via php

Tags: php, odbc

Estou com um sistema que não criei, o banco roda em `sybase` com driver `odbc`, o `php` acessa tudo com `odbc`, preciso fazer download de PDFs que estão gravados neste banco na coluna arquivo do tipo `long binary`.
Faço a seguinte consulta no banco mais o que me retorna e o texto criptografado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$result = odbc_exec($connect , $sql);
$conteudo = odbc_result($result, "arquivo");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf; name='teste'" ); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo $conteudo;
```

Já fiz com cabeçalho mais o arquivo só retorna corrompido.

Vocês sabem outra forma que possa tentar porque procurei em tudo canto e não achei.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso como uso `Xampp` ele por default limita a quantidade de dados da consulta, então no arquivo `php.ini` na linha `odbc.defaultlrl = 4092` alterei seu valor para `10mb` que corresponde a `10485760` bytes. Após fazer o teste novamente com o cabeçalho `header("Content-Type: application/pdf" );` o pdf foi exibido normal.